# Need to stop wordpress post loop

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
             <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

I took this code from the `index.php` file from the 2013 theme. I pasted this code into my website to allow me to edit things later. It works. BUT it displays all posts wherever I place the above code, but I need to have it only display posts for certain sections.

How do I edit the code to stop it looping all the posts in wordpress and only display the posts I want.

Comment: What kind of posts do you want to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you looking for. You can get a post by its slug.

```
<?php
$the_slug = 'my_slug';
$args=array(
'name' => $the_slug,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'numberposts' => 1
);
$my_posts = get_posts($args);
if( $my_posts ) {
 echo 'ID on the first post found '.$my_posts[0]->ID;
}
?>
```

Comment: I dont know what a slug is sorry

Comment: You can see a post's slug if you "quick edit" a post.

Comment: Ok, I placed the slug in, and now it displays 'ID on the first post found '. I'm sorry that I don't understand this. I really am not familiar with WP

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a new WP_Query object.  The nice thing about this is that it can be nested inside other loop, if needed - `wp_reset_query()` should prevent the nested query from affecting the main query.

```
<?php
    $new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 5
    ) );
?>

<?php if ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : $new_loop->the_post(); ?>

            // Your loop here

    <?php endwhile;?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I quite understand. So I would place this code where my current one is placed. But I would put mine inside of the `//your loop here`? I'm just not very good with WP and just need to make sure that I am understanding this correctly.

Comment: @user3487372 No, the `// Your loop here` is where you would make the data that is to be printd to the page, such as, `<h1 class="title"> <?php the_title(); ?></h1>`, he's saying that you need to modify the loop that you're iterating over. Such as, if it were a specific post type, you would change `'post_type' => 'post'` to be `'post_type', => 'custom_post_type'` for instance.

Comment: I think I may have figured out a way to do it. So every post I make has it's own post page. I was thinking If I am able to grab the php code that displays the post to that specific post page I can place it on my parallax page. How would I find the php code that is displaying a certain post?

Comment: @user3487372 You need to read [The wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org) - These questions will all be answered after a few hours of reading, trial, and error.

Comment: Ok, but for a post to be displayed on a specific page, it must have php code that tells the page WHICH post to display no? That is all I would need.

Comment: Yes, you do. WP_Query can filter the posts however you like - by type, by date, or by specific post.  See here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

I think this code helpful to you

```
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args=array('post_type' => 'post','posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => $paged);
    query_posts($args); 
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  

    // Your loop here

  <?php endwhile; ?> 
    <?php endif; ?>
```